# How to call a WebMethod from Asp.Net without using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have a bunch of     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] that I call with jquery to provide ajax functionality. Is there to call them from my codebehind files?

Meaning I have the following WebMethod in a file called DeleteImages.aspx.cs

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string deleteImage(int id, int itemID, string fileName)
{
    string deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM tItemsFiles WHERE ID=@ID";
    //run sql command
}
```

is there a way I can call this webmethod from a different codebehind file, ie CreateImage.aspx.cs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do call it directly from `CreateImage`:

```
DeleteImages.deleteImage(123, 456, "image.png");
```

(Note that I'm not sure what your actual namespace or class names are. It's almost certain that the class name of `DeleteImages.aspx.cs` will be `DeleteImages`, but you may need to prefix it with a namespace when calling it, or have a `using` directive at the top of your `CreateImage` class.)